# WriteRaster doesn't work

Tags: python, raster, gdal

I am new with gdal. I am trying to calc NDVI. But I have some problems, so I try to do some simple test, but the 
"dataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteRaster(...)" doesn't work, this result an empty image

My code is:

```
 #A function to create the output image
 def createOutputImage(self, outFilename, rb_ds):
    # Define the image driver to be used 
    # This defines the output file format TIF
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName( "Gtiff" )

    # Check that this driver can create a new file.
    metadata = driver.GetMetadata()
    if metadata.has_key(gdal.DCAP_CREATE) and metadata[gdal.DCAP_CREATE] == 'YES':
        print 'Driver GTiff supports Create() method.'
    else:
        print 'Driver GTIFF does not support Create()'
        sys.exit(-1)

    # Get the spatial information from the input file
    geoTransform = rb_ds.GetGeoTransform()
    geoProjection = rb_ds.GetProjection()
    # Create an output file of the same size as the inputted 
    # image, but with only 1 output image band.
    newDataset = driver.Create( outFilename, rb_ds.RasterXSize, \
                                rb_ds.RasterYSize, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)


    # Define the spatial information for the new image.

    newDataset.SetGeoTransform(geoTransform)
    newDataset.SetProjection(geoProjection)

    return newDataset


# The function which loops through the input image and
# calculates the output NDVI value to be outputted.    
def calcNDVI(self, red_band, NIR_band, outFilePath):
    # Open the red band dataset
    red_band_dataset = gdal.Open( red_band, gdal.GA_ReadOnly )
    nir_band_dataset = gdal.Open( NIR_band, gdal.GA_ReadOnly )

    # Check the dataset was successfully opened
    if (red_band_dataset is None) or (nir_band_dataset is None):
        print "The datasets could not openned"
        sys.exit(-1)

    # Create the output dataset
    outDataset = self.createOutputImage(outFilePath, red_band_dataset)
    # Check the datasets was successfully created.
    if outDataset is None:
        print 'Could not create output image'
        sys.exit(-1)

    # Load de two band
    red = red_band_dataset.GetRasterBand(1)

    for line in range(red.YSize):
        # read a line
        red_scanline = red.ReadRaster(0, line, red.XSize, 1, red.XSize, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)

        outDataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteRaster(0,line,red.XSize, 1, red_scanline, buf_xsize=red.XSize,buf_ysize=1, buf_type=gdal.GDT_Float32)


        del outputLine

    print "NDVI calculate correct"
```

Just I am copy line for line from red (image) to outputDataset, but I have an empty image

I am using this resource: http://learningzone.rspsoc.org.uk/index.php/Learning-Materials/Python-Scripting/9.4-Calculate-NDVI-using-GDAL

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without you providing the output (does "NDVI calculate correct" print?) it looks like this program will throw an error when trying to `del outputLine`, as `outputLine` isn't declared. This crash will result in a created image with a single line written, but otherwise the tiff will be blank.

Comment: Hello, sorry but that is not the complete code. I reduced it to ask a "simple" question. The code print NDVI calculate correct without error, but with a blank img